# Validating client certificates in PyOpenSSL

Tags: python, validation, ssl, client-certificates, pyopenssl

I'm writing an app that requires a cert to be installed in the client browser. I've found this in the PyOpenSSL docs for the "Context" object but I can't see anything about how the callback is supposed to validate the cert, only that it should, somehow.

```
   set_verify(mode, callback)
      Set the verification flags for this Context object to mode and
      specify that callback should be used for verification callbacks.
      mode should be one of VERIFY_NONE and VERIFY_PEER. If
      VERIFY_PEER is used, mode can be OR:ed with
      VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT and VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE to further
      control the behaviour. callback should take five arguments: A
      Connection object, an X509 object, and three integer variables,
      which are in turn potential error number, error depth and return
      code. callback should return true if verification passes and
      false otherwise.
```

I'm telling the Context object where my (self signed) keys are (see below) so I guess I don't understand why that's not enough for the library to check if the cert presented by the client is a valid one. What should one do in this callback function?

```
class SecureAJAXServer(PlainAJAXServer):
    def __init__(self, server_address, HandlerClass):
        BaseServer.__init__(self, server_address, HandlerClass)
        ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
        ctx.use_privatekey_file ('keys/server.key')
        ctx.use_certificate_file('keys/server.crt')
        ctx.set_session_id("My_experimental_AJAX_Server")
        ctx.set_verify( SSL.VERIFY_PEER | SSL.VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT | SSL.VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE, callback_func )
        self.socket = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(self.address_family, self.socket_type))
        self.server_bind()
        self.server_activate()
```

Caveat: Coding for fun here, def not a pro so if my Q reveals my total lameness, naivety and/or fundamental lack of understanding when it comes to SSL please don't be too rough!

**Thanks :)**

Roger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [OpenSSL documentation](http://pyopenssl.sourceforge.net/pyOpenSSL.txt) for `set_verify()`, the key that you care about is the **return code**:

> callback should take five arguments: A Connection object, an X509
>   object, and three integer variables, which are in turn potential error
>   number, error depth and **return code**. callback should return true
>   if verification passes and false otherwise.

There is a a full working example that shows more or less what you want to do: [When are client certificates verified?](https://answers.launchpad.net/pyopenssl/+question/79151)

Essentially you can ignore the first 4 arguments and just check the value of the return code in the fifth argument like so:

```
from OpenSSL.SSL import Context, Connection, SSLv23_METHOD
from OpenSSL.SSL import VERIFY_PEER, VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE

class SecureAJAXServer(BaseServer):
    def verify_callback(connection, x509, errnum, errdepth, ok):
        if not ok:
            print "Bad Certs"
        else:
            print "Certs are fine"
        return ok

    def __init__(self, server_address, HandlerClass):
        BaseServer.__init__(self, server_address, HandlerClass)
        ctx = Context(SSLv23_METHOD)
        ctx.use_privatekey_file ('keys/server.key')
        ctx.use_certificate_file('keys/server.crt')
        ctx.set_session_id("My_experimental_AJAX_Server")
        ctx.set_verify( VERIFY_PEER | VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT | VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE, verify_callback )
        self.socket = Connection(ctx, socket.socket(self.address_family, self.socket_type))
        self.server_bind()
        self.server_activate()
```

Note: I made one other change which is `from OpenSSL.SSL import ...` to simplify your code a bit while I was testing it so you don't have the `SSL.` prefix in front of every import symbol.

Comment: In this example, there is exactly zero verification being done. in fact this example you can omit `set_verify` entirely and have the exact same security characteristics. The problem is the `ok` is actually a 'return code' for pre-verification (the result of `VERIFY_PEER | VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT | VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE`) however there is exactly no client certification verification implemented in the callback - it simply returns as-is. You can just do `ctx.verify_mode` instead of `ctx.set_verify` if you make no attempt to actually implement client authentication verification

Comment: @stof if I understand what you're saying, replace `ctx.setverify(...)` with `ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE` (and remove `verify_callback()` which is no longer needed) as noted in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28048260/462302

Comment: correct, "if you make no attempt to actually implement client authentication verification" as stated. I could write you an SO Answer if you were more clear about the security outcomes you want. currently it seems you're wanting to have client validation but zero security, i.e.. no breaking a connect for failed validation.. It's very contradictory and impossible to answer